# How to sort multiple fields in an option list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm using jQuery to dynamically create an option list for a dropdown meny like so:

```
for(var i =0 ; i < response.length ; i++){
   options += '<option value="'stuff'">' +  response[i].aNumber+'-'+ response[i].aString+'-'+response[i].anotherNumber + '</option>';
}
```

What I'm looking to do is to order the option list by the String aString, second of all by aNumber and thirdly by anotherNumber.

So for example I want it to look like
Cat-1-1
Cat-2-1
Cat-2-3
Dog-1-1

I'm currently using:

```
$("#serviceCoverDropdown").html($('#serviceCoverDropdown option').sort(function(x, y) {
  return $(x).val() < $(y).val() ? -1 : 1;
 }))
```

This sorts the aString & aNumber correctly, but it doesn't group together anotherNumber well, especially if it has 2 or more digits like 10

Any ideas? Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting the response before generating the HTML:

```
response.sort(function(a, b) {
    // do sorting logic desired here
});

// now add the option nodes
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
   options += '<option value="'stuff'">' +  response[i].aNumber+'-'+ response[i].aString+'-'+response[i].anotherNumber + '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what **Peter Van Drunen** said, try this to sort the array:

```
response.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.aString.localeCompare(b.aString) || a.aNumber - b.aNumber;
});
```

Update based on the example:

```
response.sort(function (a, b) {

    return (
        a.aNumber.localeCompare(b.aNumber)
        || a.aString - b.aString
        || a.anotherNumber - b.anotherNumber
    );

});
```

Comment: Thanks James, appreciate your help, my JS isn't the best, more a backend dev. But i get this error:  a. aString.localeCompare is not a function?

Comment: @Ramonster that could happen if the "aString" property isn't a string. Looking at your example, "aString" and "aNumber" are the other way around. I've added another example that should work a little better in your situation

Comment: Thanks mate, added a toString and it worked fine, appreciate your help